# Checking if bash environment variables exist using a function

Tags: bash, environment-variables

This may have been answered in other SO posts but I don't think I can find exactly what I am looking for.

I have a (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`) function that checks for the existence of an (environment) variable

```
checkForVariable() {
  if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    echo "Error: Define $1 environment variable"
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

but in the error message I want it to tell me *which* env variable is missing.

If I call it using 
`checkForVariable "${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}"`

and if `ENVIRONMENT_NAME` is not set then obviously I will get `Error: Define environment variable` which is not useful.

How can I change my function so that I can pass `checkForVariable` a string and not a variable reference i.e.

`checkForVariable "ENVIRONMENT_NAME"`

I've tried eg. `if [[ -z "\$${1}" ]]; then` and `if [[ -z "${$1}" ]]; then` but these don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-v` and negate it using the `!`,  and the test for the `-x` attribute instead of `-z`

```
checkForVariable() {
  local env_var=
  env_var=$(declare -p "$1")
  if !  [[ -v $1 && $env_var =~ ^declare\ -x ]]; then
    echo "Error: Define $1 environment variable"
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

Then you can do the testing inside the script.

```
checkForVariable ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

This is according to help test.

```
help test | grep -- '^[[:space:]]*-v'
```

Output

```
-v VAR         True if the shell variable VAR is set.
```

And also the `!`

```
help test | grep -- '^[[:space:]]*!'
```

Output

```
! EXPR         True if expr is false.
```

Also for env variables as pointed out by chepner it is necessary to look for the `-x` attribute by testing the output of `declare -p ENV_NAME`

```
help declare | grep -- '^[[:space:]]*-x'
```

Output

```
-x        to make NAMEs export
```

Although the above works if you're testing the variable inside the script itself and not in interactive shell. Now if you want to do it in an interactive session then sourcing the file/script is needed for it to work.

Put this in your `dotfiles / rcfiles`, like in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`

```
checkForVariable() {
  local env_var=
  env_var=$(declare -p "$1")
   if ! [[  -v $1 && $env_var =~ ^declare\ -x ]]; then
     echo "Error: Define $1 environment variable"
     return 1
   fi
 }
```

Just need to replace `exit` with `return` otherwise you're interactive session will exit immediately.

And then source that rcfile.

```
source ~/.profile
```

Assuming `~/.profile` is where that function is.

You can do your test during interactive session.

```
checkForVariable ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

---

EDIT: As pointed out by chepner I have added the test for the `-x` attribute.

- Tested on GNU Linux and FreeBSD.
- See [I'm trying to write a script that will change directory (or set a variable), but after the script finishes, I'm back where I started (or my variable isn't set)!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060)

Comment: This doesn't distinguish between regular shell variables and environment variables. You would need to check for the `-x` attribute on the name as well.

Comment: @chepner, thank you for pointing that out, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 5):

You may use this function:

```
checkForVariable() {
    if [[ -z ${!1+set} ]]; then
       echo "Error: Define $1 environment variable"
       exit 1
    fi
}
```

Then use it as:

```
checkForVariable ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

Note that `${!1+set}` dereference variable using given name in `$1` to your function and `:+set` check is required to check env variables set to empty value.

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/mPIskE)

Comment: For some reason, this is not working for me. Defining a variable message is always echoed. I'm running MacOS.

Comment: Same, it still says "is not set" on all inputs.

Comment: I didn't wrap inside a function, could be related? I passed the variable directly to the script that begins with `if`.

Comment: Looks like the answer is yes. Do you know why?

Comment: Make sure you `export` your variable while calling script as `export var=123` and then call `./script.sh var` otherwise script won't find your variable.

Comment: That was it. I set it with `myvar=bla`.

Comment: I'd test it like this instead: `[[ "$(declare -p "$1")" =~ ^declare\ -x ]]`. This actually tests that the variable name in argument 1 is an exported environment variable and not a simple global variable.

Comment: @LéaGris, I have updated my answer using your test.

Comment: If your version of `bash` supports it (4.4 or later, I believe), you can use `[[ ${!1@a} = *x* ]]` as well. (The `${...@a}` operator expands to the variables attributes, rather than its value.) Indirect expansion is needed to get the name from `$1`, rather than checking `$1`'s attributes.

Comment: @chepner, that is a nice feature of 4.4, the only thing is that my vim-syntax highlighting becomes red :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have env in your shebang you can do:

```
printenv | grep "^ENV_VARIABLE"
```

or you can use set:

```
set | grep -E "^ENV_VARIABLE=.+$"
```

And also a python oneliners:

```
python3 -c 'import os; import sys; print(bool(os.getenv(sys.argv[1])))'  HOME
```

You can chek printenv result in other way of course:

```
[ ! -z `printenv VAR` ] || echo "VAR not exists"
```

So in your function become

```
function checkEnv() { [ ! -z `printenv $1` ] || echo "$1 Error message.."; }
```